# Persist mongodb aggregation pipelines

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to make agreagatin pipelines persistant like sql views?

lets say you have some agregation as for instance:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,name:1}}])
```

Is it possible to make it persistant?

As far as I unerstand the `$out` is only saves the current output of the query it does not reevaluate each time as you access the `$out` collection.

so `$out` is more similiar to the `INTO` statment in `SQL`

Is there an equivalent to `CREATE VIEW` ?

Comment: Try [**`db.createView`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/)

Comment: @chridam Ty it works